# Can you solve for the inverse using cross multiplication?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*Not a math person so bear with me. I'll try and use examples to the best of my ability*

So with cross-multiplication, when the second numerator increases in value, the unknown will increase in value.

example: $\frac31 = \frac6x$ where $x=2$

when the second numerator decreases in value, the unknown will decrease in value.

example: $\frac84 = \frac4x$ where $x=1$

My question is that is there are formula for when the second numerator increases in value, the unknown will DECREASE in value? And when the second numerator decrease in value, the unknown will INCREASE in value?

Comment: Between your two examples, **all** numbers involved changed. If you change **all** numbers, then the solution for $x$ might increase, decrease or remain the same.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This should be tagged [tag:algebra-precalculus], not [tag:abstract-algebra]

Comment: Like @AnginaSeng said, try keeping some numbers constant. You can then easily recognise a pattern

Comment: ok to clarify: with normal cross multiplication, when the second numerator is greater than the first numerator (3 < 6) the unknown denominator will be greater than the known denominator (1 < x). Same with the other example. When the second numerator is lesser than the first (8 > 4) the unknown denominator will be lesser than the known denominator (4 > x)

so I'm asking is the a function or formula or something that will give the opposite effect?